# Identify tool and highlighting behaviour in QGIS 2.6

Tags: qgis, qgis-2.6, gui, qgis-2.8

I have a problem with the identify tool in QGIS 2.6.

Somehow the object highlighting doesn't go off when i click on another object with the identify tool in QGIS.
In earlier versions, when you clicked on object after object, only the last object clicked was highlighted, highlighting on the previous one was turned off.
Note- it only happens when i let QGIS auto-open feature attributes form and highlight of an object stays on until i close the form.
Is there a hidden feature somewhere, that i can use to change this behaviour?

Comment: I don't think there is an option for this as I also couldn't find it but you could open up a [ticket](http://hub.qgis.org/projects/quantum-gis) to _highlight_ the issue :)

Comment: You want the form to stay open but the highlighting to go away?

Comment: Up until version 2.6, on click the previous highlighting went off, but the form stayed open. I would like to have the same behaviour in 2.6.

Answer (score 1):

I issued a bug report and got this response:
"The behavior changed from previous qgis releases, but this is known and was by design."
So its not a bug. Just have to get used to it.